# set expiry for Hashmap values in Redis?

Tags: redis

How do I set expiry for hashmaps in Redis like I do for regular values using SETX.
I want to provide TTL for a session for which I am storing a hasmap.
Can I create a Hashmap using SETEX itself ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can't create hash with `SETEX` (which is a strings methods). You can call `EXPIRE` on hash key, but that will expire the whole hash. There's no support at the moment for expiration of individual hash key/value pairs.

### Update:

If you wanted to set expiration on the whole hash while setting its individual elements, you can achieve that in several ways.

1. Use pipelining. Pipelining is a special mode of operation where redis client issues several commands in quick succession, not waiting for a reply to send next one. Here's an example in ruby:

   ```
   redis.pipelined do
     redis.hset "foo", "bar", 1
     redis.expire "foo", 300
   end
   ```
2. Use transactions. Without watched keys this is similar to pipelining (for a transaction can't abort). The commands are guaranteed to run together and atomically (several pipelines can run interleaved, transactions are serialized)

   ```
   redis.multi do
     redis.hset "foo", "bar", 1
     redis.expire "foo", 300
   end
   ```
3. Use [lua scripting](http://redis.io/commands/eval) to implement your custom HSETEX command. It will be executed atomically and you just have to send one command (instead of 2(pipelining) or 4 (transaction)).